# Examples in ergodic theory and topological dynamics

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, soft-question, big-list, ergodic-theory

I am currently studying basic ergodic theory:

- Invariant measures
- Poincaré recurrence theorem
- Invariant measure for continuous transformations
- The ergodic theorems and applications
- Ergodic transformations
- Unique ergodicity
- Mixing transformations
- Ergodic decomposition
- Metric entropy
- Variational principle

I already had a course in this subject. I want to deepen my understanding of this subject,I know the importance they play the examples and counter-examples for each topic listed above to achieve this goal.

Throughout the course I had to ergodic theory, I had some canonical examples in each of these topics. But in my view the list of examples was rather sparse. I wish you could talk me a list of examples, even a single example of his predilection, that you think might enhance my understanding of this subject.

**An example**: A transformation topologically mixing, which is not mixing or  an example of the space of ergodic measures is not closed in the weak-* topology... Things like this

I hope you can help me.

Comment: As it stands this is a very broad question and I'm not sure it's possible to give a good answer.  You'll probably get more helpful responses if you ask about specific examples/counterexamples that you'd like to see or understand better.

Comment: I already know some basic examples, which are usually given in the course notes. I would like examples of unusual or curious, which I do not know. So I can not leave the question less vague.

Comment: Good question. I'd like to meet some interesting examples too. I believe that Juan does not necessarily want a list of examples, but examples of knowing one's personal preference.

Answer (score 4):

The best list of classic examples are in the book Ergodic Problems of Classical Mechanics by V. I. Arnold and A. Avez. You can find a huge list of examples in the book Introduction to the Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems by Anatole Katok, Boris Hasselblatt.

Answer (score 3):

A productive way to gain the intuition you are seeking is to work through a structured set of exercises in ergodic theory. I would recommend:

[Charles Walkden's exercises](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cwalkden/ergodic-theory/exercises.pdf), based on these [lecture notes](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cwalkden/ergodic-theory/ergodic_theory.pdf)

You'll find some of the items on your wish list, such as an example that Poincaré's recurrence theorem does not hold on infinite measure spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The "examples" in the "ergodic" literature don't seem very useful for physicists.  For the latter I strongly recommend "Canonical Ensembles from Chaos" by Kusnezov, Bulgac, Bauer, Annals of Physics 204, 155-185 ( 1990 ), which has plenty of examples of the useful sort.

Bill Hoover, Ruby Valley NV